# Java Selenium and Appium doesn't work Could not start REST http interface listener

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

I using Java, selenium and appium for automation testing web application on android

I use this code:

```
        service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildDefaultService();
        service.start();
        if (service == null || !service.isRunning())
            throw new AppiumServerHasNotBeenStartedLocallyException("An appium server node is not started!");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilitiesAndroid = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilitiesAndroid.setCapability("deviceName", "Android Emulator");
        capabilitiesAndroid.setCapability("deviceOrientation", "portrait");
        capabilitiesAndroid.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.0.0");
        capabilitiesAndroid.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilitiesAndroid.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome");
        driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(capabilitiesAndroid);
```

With the same parameter I can open new session in appium. In Java I got 2 times this error:

```
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.6.5
[HTTP] Could not start REST http interface listener. The requested port may already be in use. Please make sure there is no other instance of this server running already.

Error: listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:4723
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1041:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1064:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1322:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1370:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1492:7)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:141:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

I haven't started process node.exe. Anyone know why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use the same port to initialize one more instance. You can initialize with different port. Your code tries to initialize the instance with same port number every time. You can use the below code to solve the issue.

```
 service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService( new
      AppiumServiceBuilder().usingDriverExecutable(new File(
      "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe")) .withAppiumJS(new File(
      "C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\build\lib\main.js"
      )) .withIPAddress("127.0.0.1").usingAnyFreePort());

     service.start();
```

Comment: Thank you for help but I haven't appium.js in this path, I have here ..\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\build\lib\appium.js - when I put this path occurs error  `io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServerHasNotBeenStartedLocallyException: The local appium server has not been started. The given Node.js executable: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe Arguments: [C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\build\lib\appium.js, --port, 12619, --address, 127.0.0.1]`

Comment: When I remove withAppiumJS occurs only 1 time error from my main post, but chrome on android run succefully but when some action e.g. click() must be executed occurs error java.lang.NullPointerException on click() function

Comment: I have edited the path in the answer, You can try running with new path

Comment: Almost working. I changed AppiumJS path and repalace constructor for driver to `this.driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilitiesAndroid);`
Now occurs olny null pointer exception when some action execute e.g. `driver.findElement(By.id(path)).sendKeys(text);` Do you know why?

Comment: There could be two reasons for nullpointer. The element might not found on the screen Or the driver is not initialized properly. You can debug and check the value of driver or element at run time

Comment: I know the reason I must change initialize of driver to `this.driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilitiesAndroid);`

Comment: No, pass the service object instead of new URL(). And use AndroidDriver<MobileElement>

Comment: I changed to `this.driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(service, capabilitiesAndroid);` but it doesn't work, occurs error `java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:275)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.clear(RemoteWebElement.java:117)`